# Why I can't disable multiple checkbox with IE with this JS script?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox

I did a simple script in order to disable multiple checkboxes on my .ASP App. Here's the code :

```
function updateCheckboxes(cb) 
{
    if (cb.checked) {
        document.getElementById("cb1").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("cb2").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("cb3").disabled = true;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("cb1").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("cb2").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("cb3").disabled = false;
    }
 }
```

And the HTML :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Test" onchange="updateCheckboxes(this)"/>
```

It works perfectly on Firefox but not on IE. I don't really understand why, someone can explain me where is the problem and how to find an alternative ?

Best regards,

Alex

Comment: I think this has your answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848016/checkbox-not-working-properly-for-ie-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I find the solution, the problem was the onChange() with IE.

```
function updateCheckboxes(cb) 
{
    var isChecked = cb.checked;
    document.getElementById("cb1").disabled = isChecked;
    document.getElementById("cb2").disabled = isChecked;
    document.getElementById("cb3").disabled = isChecked;
    document.getElementById("cb4").disabled = isChecked
}
```

And HTML with OnClick() :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Test" onclick="updateCheckboxes(this)"/>
```